# Acer Iconia A500 factory reset won't restart

Tags: factory-reset

My Acer A500 froze, with a blank screen ( complaining of low memory at that time), so I did a factory reset. Now the screen comes up with the ACER logo but doesn't do anything else within hours; I've tried to factory reset again but same effect. Any ideas on how I can force a start?
Gerry

Answer (score 0):

Boot up your phone. When it gets stuck on the logo, remove battery then place it again.

Comment: For the sake of potential future viewers: The Iconia A500 is a tablet without a removable battery.